# How to resize TinyMCE editor's height dynamically accordingly to text length

Tags: html, angular, tinymce, editor

Here is something i'm trying, but I think the logic isn't very right.

I'm trying to use the editor's text contents and dynamically determining the editor's height.

At tinymce.component.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    tinymce.init({
             convert_urls: false,
             selector: '#' + this.elementId,
             // ....
             // .... more properties...
             // ....
             setup: editor => {
                editor.on('SetContent',function(e){
                  const content = e.content;

                  var newHeight = String(content.length/2);
                  editor.theme.resizeTo("100%",newHeight);          
               });  
             },
    });
}
```

But somehow the height of the editor still doesn't seems about right and dynamic. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: at which point are you initializing the tiny mce ? i mean to ask the life cycle hook ?

Comment: @web-master-now i'm doing it at ngAfterViewInit().... is it the right place to do? Somehow only initializing tiny mce there then my program seems to be running fine.

Comment: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/ -- a useful link. I m not very much aware of tinymce events.  Will the event setContent where you are setting height, be triggered on ngAfterViewInit itself ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Autoresize Plugin](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/autoresize/)

Example:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  tinymce.init({
    convert_urls: false,
    selector: '#editor',
    plugins: 'autoresize',
    autoresize_min_height: 100,
    autoresize_max_height: 1000,
    autoresize_bottom_margin: 0
  });
}
```

Comment: is it free? if not... is there a free way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure that TinyMCE itself free

Comment: TinyMCE is an open source project so the editor itself is "free" as long as you abide by the open source license.  The Autoresize plugin is part of the open source project.